# How to suppress references to appear in top navigation bar?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, natbib

In my beamer template, I cannot see the references section in the table of contents, but it automatically inserts that element in the top bar, with the command `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal`.

As shown it does not fit to the top bar so I just want to suppress it.

[image: References section gets out of document]

I use *natbib* package and my reference frame looks like this:

```
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \framesubtitle{}
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

**Edit:** it does not appear in outline frame (TOC).

Comment: please create a working minimal example

Comment: It could be due to natbib package or the `\beamertemplatearticlebibitems` code. 

I made toc at the beggining and then named the sections and used the `\frametitle` to name my frames. That gave me TOC appearing in header, rather than bibliography.

Also it could be due to the theme you're using... Give us a MWE so that ppl could reproduce your problem.